# Need help on this issue openpyxl.utils.exceptions.IllegalCharacterError

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, writer

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

from openpyxl.workbook import workbook

df_1 = pd.read_csv('11-13-2019_4_43_12_AM_AP_Aging_PLEX.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1")

df_2 = pd.read_csv('11-13-2019_4_59_24_AM_AP_Aging_EUR.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1")

df_3 = pd.read_csv('11-13-2019_5_34_29_AM_AP_Aging_USD.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1")

df_4 = pd.read_csv('11-13-2019_5_36_35_AM_AP_Aging_GBP.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1")


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('platby.xlsx')

df_1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='czk', index=None)

df_2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='eur', index=None)

df_3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='usd', index=None)

df_4.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='gbp', index=None)

writer.save()
```

but I get this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "jita.py", line 12, in
>   
>       df_1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='czk', index=None)   File "C:\Users\PanZak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",
>   line 2250, in to_excel
>       formatter.write(   File "C:\Users\PanZak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py",
>   line 734, in write
>       writer.write_cells(   File "C:\Users\PanZak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_openpyxl.py",
>   line 416, in write_cells
>       xcell.value, fmt = self._value_with_fmt(cell.val)   File "C:\Users\PanZak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py",
>   line 239, in value
>       self._bind_value(value)   File "C:\Users\PanZak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py",
>   line 215, in _bind_value value = self.check_string(value)   File
>   "C:\Users\PanZak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py",
>   line 182, in check_string
>       raise IllegalCharacterError openpyxl.utils.exceptions.IllegalCharacterError

Is there any help?

Thank you

Comment: I think your .csv files have some incorrect characters then. Maybe first try to create a simple csv and try to load that.

Comment: Clearly your code isn’t a [mre] because the error is related to `df_1` so you don’t need the other four df_* And your purported [mre] is inadequate without a *small* csv file which shows the problem.

Comment: I suspect there is a problem with the encoding you're using. The exception is letting you know early that there is a problem. You can check the openpyxl for a list of the characters and build a filter.